# PHP - Preventing SQL Injection on INSERT STATEMENT

Tags: php, sql, insert

I'll keep this short and simple, I am trying to apply some code to my insert query to prevent SQL injections. See the code below:

```
$insertquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, username, password) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($fname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($lname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', .'".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."')");
            header("location:index-login-page.php?msg1=Thank you for choosing SIAA, please login.");
```

The above code does not insert any data but it still prints the msg1 message. What am I doing wrong or is it even possible to prevent SQL injections on an insert statement.

Thank You

Sohail.

Comment: there is a popular question in sof. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Basic debugging: echo your query before executing it. What is displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PDO and prepared queries.Use prepared statements and parameterized queries. These are SQL statements that are sent to and parsed by the database server separately from any parameters. This way it is impossible for an attacker to inject malicious SQL.Have a look at below example.

```
($conn is a PDO object)

$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES(:firstname, :lastname)");
$stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi Ninju, where you've placed ($conn is a PDO object) - I'm getting an error saying unexpected 'is'.. why is this?

Comment: i have edited my answer.Using PDO to access a MySQL database real prepared statements are not used by default.

Comment: but what if I've written 'include("dbconfig.php")' on top of my php file?

Comment: You need to set the PDO connection in dbconfig.php.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that now.

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error that says 'unexpected 'is' (T_STRING)

Comment: Check this example http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/  you will get an idea

Comment: I've never worked with PDO before, so it's a bit difficult for me to grasp so quickly. I'm used to the old method. Isn't there anyway to prevent an SQL injection using the older method?

Comment: otherwise you can use mysql_real_escape_string .$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94093/discussion-between-sohail-arif-and-ninju).

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statements, this will solve the problem in any case. In this way the user input is beeing send seperatly and has no way of tampering with the Query.

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Or [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)